# Compute the differential of function with 2 variables: how to specify the dependance of 2 variables

Tags: matlab

I try to compute the differential of a function depending of 2 variables : v and t

The symbolic functions are defined as :

```
d=100;
syms f g h c x v t alpha
alpha=1;
c=4/100

g=c*(v/90)^alpha;
h=diff(g,v);
m=c*(v/90)^alpha*v*t;

%% Derivatives for differential
firstTerm=diff(m,v);
secondTerm=diff(m,t);
firstTermFunction=matlabFunction(firstTerm);
secondTermFunction=matlabFunction(secondTerm);

% Direct computation of integral
f=int(2*d/(2*v^2-h*v^4),v);

vInit=50;
vMax=500;

j=matlabFunction(f);
htMatlab=matlabFunction(f-j(vInit));

v_start=vInit;
step=0.01;
v_final=vMax;
vNew=v_start:step:v_final;

% Function to integrate
htIntegral=@(v)integral(htMatlab,v_start,v); 
% Integrate numerically
ht=abs(arrayfun(htIntegral,vNew);

% Take only positive values for ht(vNew) = time
j_sorted=find(ht<10);
t_sorted(1:numel(j_sorted))=ht(j_sorted);

% Set sum of diff to 0
sumDiff=0;
i=0;
while ((sumDistance<d) && (i<(numel(vNew)-1)))
   i=i+1;
sumDistance=sumDistance+vLast(i)*(t_sorted(i+1)-t_sorted(i));
sumDiff=sumDiff+firstTerm(vLast(i),t_sorted(i))*(vLast(i+1)-vLast(i))+secondTerm(vLast(i),t_sorted(i))*(t_sorted(i+1)-t_sorted(i));          
end
```

My issue is about the functions `firstTermFunction` and `secondTermFunction` :

As you can see, both depend of variables `v` and `t`.

I would like to evalute these functions on points `t=t_sorted(i)` and `v_i=vLast(i)` but I don't know how to perform this operation, since I don't know how to specify the dependance of `v` and `t` for both.

If someone could help me how to evaluate the Matlab function `firstTermFunction` and `secondTermFunction` and what syntax to use for that :

I tried to do it by doing directly : `firstTermFunction(vLast(i),t_sorted(i))` and `secondTermFunction(vLast(i),t_sorted(i))` but I get an error.

### Update 1

My issue may come from the conversion of symbolic to numerical function with `matlabFunction`: indeed, I don't specify the dependence after the conversion.

### Update 2

With this syntax:

```
firstTermFunction=@(v,t) matlabFunction(firstTerm);
```

I get at the execution :

```
>> firstTermFunction

firstTermFunction =

  function_handle with value:

    @(v,t)matlabFunction(firstTerm)
```

and if I test now the value firstTerm(1,1) (i.e with `v=1` and `t=1`), I get :

```
>> firstTermFunction(1,1)

ans =

  function_handle with value:

    @(t,v)t.*sqrt(v.*(1.0./9.0e1)).*(1.0./2.5e1)+t.*v.*1.0./sqrt(v.*(1.0./9.0e1)).*2.222222222222222e-4
```

This is not what I expect : indeed, variables `v` and `t` are not replaced by `v=1` and `t=1` numerical values.

Comment: `i` isn't defined and `v` and `t` are symbolic variables not arrays so what you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: -@jodag Sorry, my question was badly asked. I have reformulated it and tried to be clearer.